# Resize font size to fill UITextView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitextview, font-size

How would I set the font size of text in a UITextView such that it fills the entire UITextView?  I'd like the user to type in their text, then have the text fill the entire UITextView.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 25):

I have converted [dementiazz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24884969/32598) to Swift:

```
func updateTextFont() {
    if (textView.text.isEmpty || CGSizeEqualToSize(textView.bounds.size, CGSizeZero)) {
        return;
    }

    let textViewSize = textView.frame.size;
    let fixedWidth = textViewSize.width;
    let expectSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)));

    var expectFont = textView.font;
    if (expectSize.height > textViewSize.height) {
        while (textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).height > textViewSize.height) {
            expectFont = textView.font!.fontWithSize(textView.font!.pointSize - 1)
            textView.font = expectFont
        }
    }
    else {
        while (textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).height < textViewSize.height) {
            expectFont = textView.font;
            textView.font = textView.font!.fontWithSize(textView.font!.pointSize + 1)
        }
        textView.font = expectFont;
    }
}
```

**Swift 3.0+ Update:**

```
func updateTextFont() {
    if (textView.text.isEmpty || textView.bounds.size.equalTo(CGSize.zero)) {
        return;
    }

    let textViewSize = textView.frame.size;
    let fixedWidth = textViewSize.width;
    let expectSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)));

    var expectFont = textView.font;
    if (expectSize.height > textViewSize.height) {
        while (textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).height > textViewSize.height) {
            expectFont = textView.font!.withSize(textView.font!.pointSize - 1)
            textView.font = expectFont
        }
    }
    else {
        while (textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).height < textViewSize.height) {
            expectFont = textView.font;
            textView.font = textView.font!.withSize(textView.font!.pointSize + 1)
        }
        textView.font = expectFont;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also you can add the min and max font size to avoid unexpected sizes. (too big or too small) 
I just added the condition " && (textView.font!.pointSize > CGFloat(minSize))" to your while

Comment: @RubenVot, when should we use this function?

Comment: Not Working for me. Is there anything do i need to taking care for ?

Comment: Important is to run it in the right moment. After UITextView gets the right frame. In my case in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: this doesn't deal with line orphan letters, does anyone know how i can do that?

Comment: The "Swift 3.0+ Update" solution has given me exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much Matt.

Answer (score 8):

This, in a category on UITextView, should do the trick. For why you need the fudgefactor, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095545/string-length-with-given-font-to-fit-uitextview-2-the-return)

```
#define kMaxFieldHeight 9999 

-(BOOL)sizeFontToFit:(NSString*)aString minSize:(float)aMinFontSize maxSize:(float)aMaxFontSize 
{   
float fudgeFactor = 16.0;
float fontSize = aMaxFontSize;

self.font = [self.font fontWithSize:fontSize];

CGSize tallerSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width-fudgeFactor,kMaxFieldHeight);
CGSize stringSize = [aString sizeWithFont:self.font constrainedToSize:tallerSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

while (stringSize.height >= self.frame.size.height)
       {
       if (fontSize <= aMinFontSize) // it just won't fit
           return NO;

       fontSize -= 1.0;
       self.font = [self.font fontWithSize:fontSize];
       tallerSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width-fudgeFactor,kMaxFieldHeight);
       stringSize = [aString sizeWithFont:self.font constrainedToSize:tallerSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
       }

return YES; 
}
```

Comment: in iOS >7.0 you need to change UILineBreakModeWordWrap to NSLineBreakByWordWrapping

Comment: just curious, how do you know "fudgeFactor = 16.0"? I believe this value should be smaller when text size is smaller

Answer (score 7):

Similar approach to Arie Litovsky's answer but without sub-classing (or use of a category) and not using `contentSize` which didn't return the correct height of the rendered text for me. Tested on iOS 7:

```
while (((CGSize) [_textView sizeThatFits:_textView.frame.size]).height > _textView.frame.size.height) {
    _textView.font = [_textView.font fontWithSize:_textView.font.pointSize-1];
}
```

The approach is to keep reducing the font size until the text just fits inside the frame of the text view.

If you were going to use this in production you would still need to:

- Handle the case where even with the smallest-possible font size the text still won't fit.
- Use a similar approach to *increase* the font size if you would also like to scale text *up* to fit the frame.

Answer (score 6):

Try this, it's a lot simpler:

```
while (self.contentSize.height > self.frame.size.height)
{
    self.font = [self.font fontWithSize:self.font.pointSize -1];
    [self layoutSubviews];//force .contentSize to update
}
```

Comment: @BradMoore, you need to add one more line: [textView layoutSubviews];

Comment: @Jacky, good to know! If I revisit this code I'll see if its worth updating.

Comment: @Jacky - it's actually [textView layoutIfNeeded] you want to call

Comment: @BradMoore This should be top answer. I also noticed this was answered in 2012, resolution is so high these days that fractional font sizes should be considered. I used -0.5 instead -1 and it worked very smoothly on all device sizes.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my sample code. Basically, I check the expect size to know if font size need to increase or decrease. You need to add UITextViewDelegate to your class to make sure it workings

```
- (void)updateTextFont:(UITextView *)textView
{
    // Only run if has text, otherwise it will make infinity loop
    if (textView.text.length == 0 || CGSizeEqualToSize(textView.bounds.size, CGSizeZero)) return;

    /*
     - Update textView font size
     If expectHeight > textViewHeight => descrease font size n point until it reach textViewHeight
     If expectHeight < textViewHeight => inscrease font size n point until it reach textViewHeight
     */
    CGSize textViewSize = textView.frame.size;
    CGFloat fixedWidth = textViewSize.width;
    CGSize expectSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];

    UIFont *expectFont = textView.font;
    if (expectSize.height > textViewSize.height) {
        while ([textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)].height > textViewSize.height) {
            expectFont = [textView.font fontWithSize:(textView.font.pointSize-1)];
            textView.font = expectFont;
        }
    } else {
        while ([textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)].height < textViewSize.height) {
            expectFont = textView.font;
            textView.font = [textView.font fontWithSize:(textView.font.pointSize+1)];
        }
        textView.font = expectFont;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious what the else clause is doing here. You set an `expectFont` to the `textView's` `font` before you modify it... then you set it back to the unmodified `font`? Is that to prevent the jumping up and down of the text size?

Comment: @StephenPaul in else clause, if while doesn't run, the `textView.font` doesn't change (because `expectFont` is actually original `textView.font`). But if while run at least 1 time, `expectFont` is changed and we need to update it after finish the loop. I could make a flag to determine while run or not, but I didn't. Instead, I group it into last line `textView.font = expectFont`

Comment: if the while loop runs at least 1 time, you store the current font in a variable `expectFont`. Then you increase the `textView`'s font by one point, but then when that while loop exits, you see that `textView` font back to what it was...

Comment: you set*, I meant.

Comment: Yes, because the last time `textView.font` is setted, the while condition is false (I'm using textView to calculate the condition directly). That mean the font I'm setting is not correct, and I have to roll back to expect font.

Answer (score 3):

I have converted dementiazz's & Matt Frear's answer to Swift 3:

```
func updateTextFont() {
        if (textView.text.isEmpty || textView.bounds.size.equalTo(CGSize.zero)) {
            return
        }

    let textViewSize = textView.frame.size
    let fixedWidth = textViewSize.width
    let expectSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))

    var expectFont = textView.font
    if (expectSize.height > textViewSize.height) {
        while (textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).height > textViewSize.height) {
            expectFont = textView.font!.withSize(textView.font!.pointSize - 1)
            textView.font = expectFont
        }
    }
    else {
        while (textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).height < textViewSize.height) {
            expectFont = textView.font
            textView.font = textView.font!.withSize(textView.font!.pointSize + 1)
        }
        textView.font = expectFont
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

for swift 3

```
    func updateTextFont(textView: UITextView) {
     if (textView.text.isEmpty || textView.bounds.size.equalTo(CGSize.zero)) {
        return
     }
     let textViewSize = textView.frame.size
     let fixedWidth = textViewSize.width
     let expectSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))
     var expectFont = textView.font;
     if (expectSize.height > textViewSize.height) {
        while (textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).height > textViewSize.height) {
            expectFont = textView.font!.withSize(textView.font!.pointSize - 1)
            textView.font = expectFont
        }
     }
     else {
        while (textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth,height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).height < textViewSize.height) {
            expectFont = textView.font
            textView.font = textView.font!.withSize(textView.font!.pointSize + 1)
        }
        textView.font = expectFont
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I have converted Matt Frear's answer to Swift 4.1 as extension for UITextView:

```
extension UITextView {
func updateTextFont() {
    if (self.text.isEmpty || self.bounds.size.equalTo(CGSize.zero)) {
        return;
    }

    let textViewSize = self.frame.size;
    let fixedWidth = textViewSize.width;
    let expectSize = self.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))


    var expectFont = self.font
    if (expectSize.height > textViewSize.height) {

        while (self.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).height > textViewSize.height) {
            expectFont = self.font!.withSize(self.font!.pointSize - 1)
            self.font = expectFont
        }
    }
    else {
        while (self.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).height < textViewSize.height) {
            expectFont = self.font
            self.font = self.font!.withSize(self.font!.pointSize + 1)
        }
        self.font = expectFont
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Max Font Size**

If you would like the size of the font in your `UITextView` to not exceed a certain point size, I added that functionality to Matt's answer. I also put it in an extension of `UITextView` to make it easier to use.

```
extension UITextView {
    /// Autosizes the font to fit the UITextView's text in its frame
    /// - Parameter max: The maximum point size the font should get
    func updateTextFont(max: CGFloat) {
        if (self.text!.isEmpty || self.bounds.size.equalTo(CGSize.zero)) {
            return;
        }
        
        let textViewSize = self.frame.size;
        let fixedWidth = textViewSize.width;
        let expectSize = self.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)));
        
        var expectFont = self.font;
        if (expectSize.height > textViewSize.height) {
            while (self.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).height > textViewSize.height) && (self.font!.pointSize <= max) {
                expectFont = self.font!.withSize(self.font!.pointSize - 1)
                self.font = expectFont
            }
        } else {
            while (self.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).height < textViewSize.height) && (self.font!.pointSize <= max) {
                expectFont = self.font;
                self.font = self.font!.withSize(self.font!.pointSize + 1)
            }
            self.font = expectFont;
        }
    }
}
```

I found it best to call in `UITextView`'s delegate method `textViewDidChange`

```
class UIViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!
    
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textView.updateTextFont(max: 40)
    }
}
```

*This has also been updated for Swift 5.1*

Answer (score 2):

This property is only available on UITextFields. To do this in a UITextView, you'd have to constantly watch the text and manually adjust the font size as that changed.

Comment: Ah, is there any sample code out there that does this?  I looked around and couldn't find anything.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm not aware of any sample code; I've never heard of anyone trying to do this before.

Answer (score 2):

Hope that's clearer:

```
extension UITextView {
    @objc public func fitText() {
        fitText(into: frame.size)
    }

    @objc public func fitText(into originalSize: CGSize) {
        let originalWidth = originalSize.width
        let expectedSize = sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: originalWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))

        if expectedSize.height > originalSize.height {
            while let font = self.font, sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: originalWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).height > originalSize.height {
                self.font = font.withSize(font.pointSize - 1)
            }
        } else {
            var previousFont = self.font
            while let font = self.font, sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: originalWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).height < originalSize.height {
                previousFont = font
                self.font = font.withSize(font.pointSize + 1)
            }
            self.font = previousFont
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In viewDidLoad:

```
textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

You need to add UITextViewDelegate:

```
- (void)updateTextFont:(UITextView *)textView {

    CGSize textViewSize = textView.frame.size;
    CGSize sizeOfText = [textView.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: textView.font}];

    CGFloat fontOfWidth = floorf(textView.font.pointSize / sizeOfText.height * textViewSize.height);
    CGFloat fontOfHeight = floorf(textView.font.pointSize / sizeOfText.width * textViewSize.width);

    textView.font = [textView.font fontWithSize:MIN(fontOfHeight, fontOfWidth)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An updated version of @Arie Litovsky's code. This works in iOS7 and later and stretches the font size both up and down so the text fits.

```
- (void) stretchFontToFit:(UITextView*)textView
{

    while( textView.contentSize.height < textView.frame.size.height )
    {
        textView.font = [textView.font fontWithSize:textView.font.pointSize +1];
        [textView layoutIfNeeded];
    }

    while( textView.contentSize.height > textView.frame.size.height )
    {
        textView.font = [textView.font fontWithSize:textView.font.pointSize -1];
        [textView layoutIfNeeded];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a conversion of [dementiazz's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24884969/32598) and [Matt Frear's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27115350/6741074) answer to Swift 5. Put this function into viewDidLayoutSubviews, referencing the UITextView's who's font you want to dynamically resize.

```
func updateTextFont(textView: UITextView) {
    if (textView.text.isEmpty || textView.bounds.size.equalTo(CGSize.zero)) {
        return;
    }

    let textViewSize = textView.frame.size;
    let fixedWidth = textViewSize.width;
    let expectSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))

    var expectFont = textView.font;
    if (expectSize.height > textViewSize.height) {
        while (textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).height > textViewSize.height) {
            expectFont = textView.font!.withSize(textView.font!.pointSize - 1)
            textView.font = expectFont
        }
    }
    else {
        while (textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).height < textViewSize.height) {
            expectFont = textView.font;
            textView.font = textView.font!.withSize(textView.font!.pointSize + 1)
        }
        textView.font = expectFont;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

U can easily do this by using

- `self.textview.font` =

> self.textview.font =  UIFont(name: self.textview.font!.fontName,
>   size: self.textview.frame.size.height / 10)!

divide textview.frame.size.height upon some constant based on your requirement..

Answer (score -2):

Here is a solution for **Swift 4** (based on [Arie Litovsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/504912/arie-litovsky) answer), you can put this code into `textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView)` delegate method :

Scaling down the font :

```
    while (textView.contentSize.height > textView.frame.size.height) {
        guard let fontName = textView.font?.fontName, let fontSize = textView.font?.pointSize else {return}
        if fontSize < 12 {
            return
        }
        textView.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: fontSize - 1)
        textView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

And scaling up the font:

```
        while (textView.contentSize.height < textView.frame.size.height) {
        guard let fontName = textView.font?.fontName, let fontSize = textView.font?.pointSize else {return}
        if fontSize > 15 {
            return
        }
        textView.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: fontSize + 1)
        textView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

You can change the `fontSize < 12` and `fontSize > 15` to fit your needs in minimum and maximum font size.