# Reducing font Size in uiTextView.

Tags: xcode, ios7, uitextview, contentsize

I have the following code in an app to reduce the size of the font to fit the fixed uiTextView

```
if (pdThree.contentSize.height > pdThree.frame.size.height) {
    int fontIncrement = 1;
    while (pdThree.contentSize.height > pdThree.frame.size.height) {
        pdThree.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:kDefaultFontSize-fontIncrement];
        fontIncrement++;
    }
}
```

However I understand that contentSize.height no longer works correctly, can anyone help with this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by doing a bit more digging around Stack Overflow. Answer here [Resize font size to fill UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038975/resize-font-size-to-fill-uitextview)

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2025180/stefan-haflidason

and here is the code I used :-

```
while (((CGSize) [pdThree sizeThatFits:pdThree.frame.size]).height > pdThree.frame.size.height) {
    pdThree.font = [pdThree.font fontWithSize:pdThree.font.pointSize-1];
}
```