# Correct way to get line number of UITextView in iOS7 and iOS8

Tags: ios, uitextview

There're already a lot of threads related to this topic, but I never could find a correct way to get line number of UITextView in iOS7 and iOS8. Below is the way that I think it's the best one, but still have some problems when text font is small. Anybody has a better solution?

Step1:Get the text height in UITextView. from: [Resize font size to fill UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038975/resize-font-size-to-fill-uitextview)

```
- (float) getTextSizeHeight:(UITextView *) textView{
    [iConsole info:@"%s",__FUNCTION__];
    CGSize tallerSize = CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width-16,999); 
    CGSize stringSize;
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
        stringSize = [textView.text sizeWithFont:textView.font constrainedToSize:tallerSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    } else {
        stringSize = [textView.text sizeWithFont:textView.font constrainedToSize:tallerSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    }  
    CGFloat textHeight = stringSize.height; //textView.contentSize.height is not the right way
    return textHeight;
}
```

Step2: calculate line number

```
- (int) lineNumberWithUITextView:(UITextView *) textView
{

    float textHeight = [self getTextSizeHeight:textView];
    float lineHeight = textView.font.lineHeight;

    float numLines = textHeight / lineHeight;

    int returnVal = ceilf(numLines);

    return returnVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in ios7 above,you can use:

```
 float rows = round((textView.contentSize.height - textView.textContainerInset.top - textView.textContainerInset.bottom) / textView.font.lineHeight);
```