# dynamic font size is not increased for textview?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am trying to have dynamic font size for the textview.I have mad a custom class for the dynamic font size of text view.I have used following code for the custom class.

```
#import "CustomTextView.h"

@implementation CustomTextView


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    int numLines = self.contentSize.height / self.font.lineHeight;
    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:self.font.fontName size:((self.frame.size.height / numLines) - 4)];
    [super drawRect: rect];

}


@end
```

but this does not work.it shows a black color for the textview.please guide how to do it?

Comment: Are you set CustomTextView Class to your text view?

Comment: here already described how we can set font size dynamically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038975/resize-font-size-to-fill-uitextview

Answer (score -1):

There must be something wrong while implementing "CustomTextView.h" in your ViewController.
Let us know how u have done the same. 
Share your code in ViewController.
Have you added "CustomTextView" as subview in your view controller.