# Scale UITextView and maintain text clarity

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

How can a `UITextView` be scaled (by `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`) without losing text clarity?

This is the blurry `UITextView` when scaled up:

[image]

This is the desired effect (created on Snapchat).

[image]

Here is my code:

```
func scale(_ sender:UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    sender.view?.transform = (sender.view?.transform.scaledBy(x: sender.scale, y: sender.scale))!
    sender.scale = 1
}
```

Comment: would you please share how you archive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `UIFont` `size` when you scale up your `UITextView`.

Otherwise your `text` will get blurry because you are scaling up the actual frame of the `UITextView` together with the `text` but the current `UIFont` is still a small `size` so you will see it as pixelated and blurry.

EDIT:
Calculate font size:

[Resize font size to fill UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038975/resize-font-size-to-fill-uitextview)

Comment: Thanks Sneak for getting back so quickly. What is the best way of changing the UIFont size in proportion to the scale?

Comment: @PeterTao You should first of all only change the font when the **gesture.state has ended**, to avoid performance issues. Second, I have never done it but basically you should calculate the textView.bounds.size.height (if it's single line text) and set an equivalant size to the font or something. The best way is if you just try and see what size works and is visually sharp without getting pixelated.

Comment: Not working for me. Is there anything do i need to taking care for?